# multicolumn repeats the cell

Tags: tables, multicolumn

at the point that I am using `\multicolumn {3}{c|}{A}` it repeats A twice in the merged column. here is the code. thanks for your helps

```
\begin{table}[h!tb]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{}  &  \multicolumn{3}{ c |}{A}\\

  & 70 & 100 & 150 \\

\hline

 Track angle [rad] & 0.047 & 0.067 & 0.100 \\

\hline

\hline

 Reference absolute carbody roll angle [rad] & 0.049 & 0.071 & 0.106 \\

\hline

 Reference swep coefficient & 0.061 & 0.062 & 0.064 \\

\hline

\hline

Tested absolute carbody roll angle [rad] & 0.051 & 0.072 & 0.108 \\

\hline

Tested swep coefficient & 0.078 & 0.078 & 0.078 \\

\hline



\end{tabular}

\caption{Sway characteristics test results}

\label{T:sway}

\end{center}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your title does not correlate to your post's text. Please describe your problem more in detail and extend your code example to a minimal, working example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: you still not provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document} which show your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this question when I happen to encounter the same issue in a recent paper. It turns out that this bug in my case is caused by the `xcolor` package with the option `table`. By changing

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
```

to

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
```

I managed to remove this bug. Don't know if there's any other way though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: (i) errors which is reported in question, can't be reproduced (question is not clear at all), (ii) from question is not follows that it deal anything with coloring of table rows/columns, (iii) even if i use `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}` it works fine. if you have some problems with it, which you solved as you say in your answer, show this in form of small complete document. the best in the new question.